# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card Input.ChoiceSet Apostrophe Rendered Differently

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I create an Adaptive Card for Microsoft Teams with an Input.ChoiceSet value and that value contains an apostrophe, Microsoft Teams OS X and web clients show `&#39;`, the iOS and Android clients show the apostrophe (correct).

What can I do differently to get the Input.ChoiceSet value to render the apostrophe in every case?

Here's the card schema and a render below.

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Command Center",
                "size": "large",
                "weight": "bolder"
              },
              {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Please choose a scenario to submit."
              },
              {
                "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                "id": "scenario-id",
                "style": "compact",
                "isMultiSelect": false,
                "value": "71ae62b1-f04e-11e9-b862-577308a243ca",
                "choices": [
                  {
                    "value": "71ae62b1-f04e-11e9-b862-577308a243ca",
                    "title": "Foo's Bar"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "16db3124-f42d-11e9-bde7-819811d8b810",
                    "title": "Second"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "actions": [
          {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "id": "popup",
            "title": "Continue...",
            "data": {
              "msteams": {
                "type": "task/fetch"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Teams OS X and Teams Android Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iRyW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

@MarkSingleWire Thanks for reporting this. We have raised a bug for this and we are looking into this internally.

Comment: Do you have a timeframe for the fix? We also have this problem with ampersands.